# How to play sound in Python?

Tags: python, audio

I'm looking for a library that would let me play sound on specific frequencies for a specified length in Python 3.8. A common search gave me libraries like winsound and pyaudio -- however these do not seem to support Python 3.8  out of the box -- and a bunch of high level libraries that cannot play anything below WAV or MP3 file formats.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can look at this: https://pypi.org/project/pysound/#data

Comment: this forum has been around for MANY years and its loaded with questions + answers on all common questions ... please put forth the effort to discover those nuggets before repeating the same question yet again ... that way you save time and this forum can avoid getting duplicate questions ... key to a good software engineer is productivity which is greatly aided through a judicial use of effort spent researching a question versus throwing up the hands and asking

Comment: Useful opinion however -- as I have said -- previous answers to not apply for one reason or another. You can imagine I didn't come to post here first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use playsound module. You can import by doing this:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('audio.mp3')
```

You can see more details here: https://pypi.org/project/playsound/

Comment: Yes, I have found this one, but as far as I know it takes mp3 files as input whereas I want to generate sound by providing frequency values only.

Comment: I do not know if it provides frequency values or not. You can see documentation for that.